# hide tabpages from another form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, hide, tabpage

I have a login form and another form. when user is x and password is y I want to show form completely and I do not have problem with this part but when user z with pass t login I wanna he could n't show 2 out of 3 of tab pages. in summary, I would be so appreciate if you could say me how to hide a tab page of a form from another form.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "x" && textBox2.Text == "123")
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 fr1 = new Form1();
            fr1.ShowDialog();

        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "z" && textBox2.Text == "t")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form1 fr1 = new Form1();
               //how can I hide 2 out of 3 tabpages on form1(fr1) for this user
                fr1.ShowDialog();




            }
         }
```

Comment: Do You also have a main-form, which starts login form, or is the login form the first one, e.g. the main form ?

Comment: How would you 'hide' tapgages in the same form??

Comment: my login form is startup form and when a user with username z and password t logged in I want he could not show tapepage2 and tabpage3 on form1(fr1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would be so appreciate if you could say me how to hide a tab page of a form from another form.

It sounds like you need a means of passing information from one `Form` to another. Often this can be achieved via the `Form` constructor, such that upon instantiation the relevant information for how to display specific controls is present. If for some reason, using the constructor approach is not ideal -- you could have a shared mechanism for which to store and gather the relevant data. Typically overriding the `OnLoad` is a good choice for making a call to gather the said data.

Once you have the data you need, you can then use it to display or hide the tab page. I usually suggest [**data binding**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) and using an [**MVVM pattern**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) for WinForms.

For example you could have a model that represents various details about the user who logged in, and then bind to various control properties.

As I mentioned you would want a way to have communicate the visibility to `Form1` from its constructor. So add this to the constructor:

```
private bool _hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs;

public Form1(bool hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs = false)
{
    _hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs = hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs;
}
```

Then override the `OnLoad` like so:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (_hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs)
    {
        foreach (var tabPage in tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>())
        {
            // TODO: Some logical test to ensure this is the desired tab control to hide
            // if (tabPage)
            {
                tabPage.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally your method will end up looking like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textOne = textBox1.Text,
        textTwo = textBox2.Text;

    if (textOne == "x" && textTwo == "123")
    {
        Hide();
        using(var fr1 = new Form1())
        {
            fr1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    else if (textOne == "z" && textTwo == "t")
    {
        Hide();
        using(var fr1 = new Form1(true))
        {
            fr1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response although in most cases I did not get the point cause I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful response. but should n't hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs  be true instead of false? i use this code     protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (_hideTwoOutOfThreeTabs)
    {
        foreach (var tabPage in tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>())
        {
            if (tabPage == tabPage2)
                tabPage2.Hide();

            if (tabPage == tabPage3)
                tabPage3.Hide();
       


      }
    }
}

Comment: It should be true when the constructor is told it's true. Look @ this line `(textOne == "z" && textTwo == "t")` in the `button1_Click`. If that is true, then the `Form1` is instantiated with `true`.

Comment: Sure, I will do it but now my reputation is not enough

Comment: I got an exception in for each section that tell me "NullRefrence Exeption occurred, object reference not set to an instance of object". I am not familiar with how to hide my tabpage2 and tabpage3 by tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>() then even I use tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2) and tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3) but I got the same Exception

Comment: Since we already know which specific tab pages you're trying to toggle, just do this instead? `if (tabPage2 != null && tabPage3 != null) { tabPage2.Visible = blah; tabPage3.Visible = blah; }`.

Comment: I typed this:  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {if (tabPage2 != null && tabPage3 != null) { tabPage2.Visible = false; tabPage3.Visible = false; }} but it hides tabpage1 too.

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question with those specific details then.